# Asus X51RLSeries Audio Drivers

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I have a Asus X51RLSeries laptop , I couldn't find Windows XP Audio drivers for that, anyone can help me to find drivers for this, I have driver CD but it mentioned that suitable for Windows Vista , any one can help me to find the solution for this??

Answer (score 3):

A SIMPLE GOOGLE SEARCH for the terms "asus X51RL" will reveal the third link to asus' support page, which then asks you what OS you run, selecting XP now lists all drivers INCLUDING audio. Please try doing some legwork before you ask questions.

Comment: this is not working I downloaded from their site but , its give an error while extracting thee zip folder , corrupted file error

Comment: I suspect you're clicking "open" instead of "save". Sometimes Windows corrupts such files if you open them, instead of saving. Try this. If not, try another mirror, i think ASUS offers different mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

wwww.support.asus.com is a great place for all asus device drivers etc.

This is a more direct link if its more useful. Just select XP on the OS List.
http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=X51RL&hashedid=LNTm9IOyCGm6yi2g

You will then see a list of devices and you can download the Audio driver from there.

Good Luck!

Comment: this is not working I downloaded from their site but , its give an error while extracting thee zip folder , corrupted file error